# Laravel remeber me, check for checkbox input

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel and need a solution.

The docs for the remember me function state that 'true' needs to be passed into the Auth method for it to work.

As per docs:

```
if (Auth::attempt($userData, true))
{
  return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

That works, but I need to check if the user has selected for their account to be remembered.

Im not sure where, but for a while I had this as a solution:

```
if (Auth::attempt($userData, ($data['rememberme'] == 'on') ? true : false))
{
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Which did not work since it was not setting a remember me token in the database.

Any guidance on how to pass true into the Auth method if the checkbox is selected? Im sure I could do a basic check to see the value and then set a variable of true / false and put that into the method. But im sure there must a better way?

Comment: If a checkbox isn't set, it won't be added to the input. So you can do something like `Auth::attempt($userData, Input::has('rememberme'))`

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley It's unclear what `$data` is, but why would the field key need to be set if the user *doesn't* want to be remembered? And how would `Input::has` change that?

Comment: @JacobBudin Unless I misunderstood, OP is submitting a standard login form with a checkbox for 'Remember Me', and wants to 'pass true into the Auth method if the checkbox is selected'. `Input::has` would return boolean true if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller Should be like this with a remember token variable :

```
       public function postSignin()
      { 
    $remember = (Input::has('remember_me')) ? true : false;

    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password'), 'active'=>0))) {
        return Redirect::to('users/signin')
            ->with('message','Please activate your account to log in');
    }
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password'), 'active'=>1),$remember)) {
        return Redirect::to('/')
            ->with('message','Thanks for signing in');
    }


    return Redirect::to('users/signin')
        ->with('message','Your Email/Password combination was incorrect');
}
```

Put a checkbox input into your form as

```
{{ Form::checkbox('remember_me') }}
```

I think It should work.. Let me know If you have any trouble. Thanks